# How can i check all my activities are completed in Amazon SWF

Tags: amazon-swf

I have requirement to run 'n' number of activities in an Asynchronous method from an workflow in SWF and once these 'n' activities are completed then only I should start my next activity from the same workflow.

Currently I am able to start the 'n' number of activities from Asynchronous method. Now the challenge is how can I get to know the completion of my 'n' activities in the workflow so that I can start my next activity?

Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Method annotated with [@Asynchronous](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/annotations/Asynchronous.html) executes only when all of its arguments that extend [Promise](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/core/Promise.html) type are in ready state. So the pattern is the following:

```
Promise<...> a = activityA();
Promise<...> b = activityB();
Promise<...> c = activityC();
Promise<...> d = activityD();
methodThatCallsActivityD(a, b, c, d);

@Asynchronous
private void methodThatCallsActivityD(
     Promise<...> a, 
     Promise<...> b, 
     Promise<...> c, 
     Promise<...> d) {
   // the body of the method is executed only when a,b,c,d are ready
   activityE();
}
```

Note that generated activity client side interfaces accept as a last parameter Promise... vararg. The semantic is that an activity is invoked only when all Prmises passed to that last parameter should be ready. So the above code can be rewritten as:

```
Promise<...> a = activityA();
Promise<...> b = activityB();
Promise<...> c = activityC();
Promise<...> d = activityD();
// activity E is invoked only when a,b,c,d are ready.
activityE(a, b, c, d);
```